# What is the working directory of a Docker Golang application?

Tags: ssl, go, docker, https

When I serve a Golang Application from within the official Docker Hub Repository I wonder what will be the default working directory the application starts up?

Background: I will have to map local Certificate Authority and server keys into the container to serve TLS https and I wonder where to map them to the application will be able to grab them in current working directory of the application from within the container?

Comment: Are you asking what the the golang image sets  for WORKDIR? You can see it in the [DOCKERFILE](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/0ce80411b9f41e9c3a21fc0a1bffba6ae761825a/1.6/Dockerfile)

Comment: But this is the WORKDIR for the build, not where the executable will finally be stored and called, or? Depends of it's a go build or go install. I barely understand the semantics of Dockerfile s

Comment: "The [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile" You can also set WORKDIR yourself in your DOCKERFILE, or use an absolute path to locate the files.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the golang:1.X-onbuild image from DockerHub will be copied into(https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/)

```
/go/src/app
```

this means all files and directories from the directory where you run the

```
docker build
```

command will be copied into the container.

And the workdir of all images is

```
/go
```

Comment: When I run docker run ... -v /home/local/cert.pem:/go/cert,pem   and try to open cert.pem in the program it complains about "file not found". So, as it seems, /go/ is not the PWD the application is executing in?

Comment: @JohnDoe: execute a `pwd` or `ls` and see where you are and what's in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Go will return the current working directory using

```
currdir, _ = filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
```

Executed within a golang container and right after startup, the pwd is set to

```
/go/src/app
```

The current working directory of a golang application starting up within a Docker container is thus `/go/src/app`. In order to map a file/directory into a container you will habe to use the `-v`-switch as described in the [Documentation for run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume-v-read-only):

```
-v /local/file.pem:/go/src/app/file.pem
```

Will map a local file into the pwd of the dockerized golang app.